# <IMG/> LowSrc attribute +  events?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

```
< IMG SRC="pete.jpg" LOWSRC="pete2.jpg" WIDTH=364 HEIGHT=500>
```

*(The low quality version, pete2.jpg, is 7,401 bytes.
The high quality version, pete.jpg, is 48,952 bytes.)*

I want to show first the `lowsrc`.

then after it finishes loading , start loading in the background the real src.

I want to display a progress bar meanwhile. but in order to hide/display the progress bar - i need **2** events.

```
when LOWSRC  load event -> show progress bar
when SRC   load event -> hide progress bar
```

how can i capture the `LOAD` event both for `lowsrc`  && `src`

### edit

ive tested [this url](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dougneiner/6871497481/in/photostream/lightbox/)

and fast-forwarded the pictures - and by fiddler i saw there are 2 images. one small and one big.

but this made me search and find the `lowsrc` attr.

which can also help here....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to various sources around the web, `lowsrc` is no longer supported by modern browsers. At least on Chrome 18 / Windows 7, it seems to get ignored completely.

It's never been part of HTML4, [nor of HTML5](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/html5-obsolete-features.html), although supposedly it's still [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement) by Gecko browsers (I did not test this).

Your best bet is to use two images, like Flickr does.