# How to show a low resolution pictures when downloading high resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have quite big image to download and show in a `img` tag.

Image it is not Progressive JPEG, so you can see image being rendered when downlaoding.

I would like to show a low resolution version when the image is fetch from the server, possibly using only CSS or an HTML property.

Any idea how to solve it?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hncajo9f/1/

Comment: what about lowsrc attribute?

Comment: @ Gibbok http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371977/img-lowsrc-attribute-events

Comment: your jsfiddle example doesn't show anything interesting that is relevant to this

Comment: what do you mean by "downloading"? if it's downloading on your website, and not on it's own (file) page, than just put a low-res background on the container where you photo needs to load, and make that low-res photo fill it, so the high-res will load in the front. (you will have to prepare 2 versions of each image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use JavaScript too to fetch, because, it needs to download the full image to create a thumbnail or some sort of low quality image. If your server side has a PHP backend, you can use GD to create a low quality image and show it here before the original one loads.

The other best way is to use a low quality image (a separate copy) in the `src` attribute and then lazy load the original image. Also, `lowsrc` attribute can be used here, but I am not sure about the support given by the browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371977/img-lowsrc-attribute-events

Comment: Thanks @kougiland, that will be useful for this question!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `srcset` attribute and read this

[Responsive Images: Use Cases and Documented Code Snippets to Get You Started](https://dev.opera.com/articles/responsive-images/)

```
<img src="opera-1x.jpg" alt="The Oslo Opera House" srcset="opera-2x.jpg 2x, opera-3x.jpg 3x">
```

or

[‘SRCSET’ ATTRIBUTE SOLVING RESPONSIVE IMAGE DILEMMA](http://html5hub.com/srcset-attribute-solving-responsive-image-dilemma/)

Comment: Not what was asked for - content selection is based on the CSS selector. Also this is HTML5.1 (but there are shims for backward compat)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the low resolution version (specifying the dimenions of the hi res) in the IMG tag then amend the URL at a later point (e.g. the window.onload event). If you specify a data uri for the low res version then you avoid an extra fetch.

```
<img 
     realurl='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Very_Large_Array,_2012.jpg'
     src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" 
 />

<script>
function hires_images()
{
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) { 
        if (imgs[i].realuri) {
            imgs[i].src=imgs[i].realuri;
        }
     }
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
     window.addEventListener('load', hires_images, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', hires_images);
}
```

Comment: this will set the image to blank while it's loading the new high-res image, and will not preload it.

Comment: I didn't say I'd tried it :) You could set the low res as the background before replacing it.